# Custom contact info in user profile not displaying

Tags: theme-development

I have created custom contact fields for Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn in user profile. But I am not able to retrieve these values on front-end. Here is the code. It is displaying empty values.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php 
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );
?>

<div class="author-info_wrapper">
    <div class="author-info-inner_wrapper">

        <ul class="list-inline social-list">

           <li>
               <a href="<?php the_author_meta('facebook'); ?>"><i class="ion-social-facebook"></i></a>
           </li>

           <li>
               <a href="<?php the_author_meta('twitter'); ?>"><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a>
           </li>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_author_meta('linkedin'); ?>"><i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i></a>
           </li>

   </ul>
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
```

I also use `echo the_author_meta()` but not worked for me.

Comment: Does these custom fields are not empty? How do you fill those up? Also you don't need to `echo` the `the_author_meta()`. [It echoes itself](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta).

Comment: Have you tried with user ID ? Like `the_author_meta('facebook', $user_id )`. Here give the user ID you know that for the user the field value exist.

Comment: Its solved. Actually I have many registered users and the data I was looking for a user was empty :)  thank you guys!

Answer (score -2):

use `get_the_author_meta()` instead of `the_author_meta()`